# Prevent SwiftUI Divider expanding horizontally

Tags: swiftui, layout

I have the following setup:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Title").font(.title)
                    
            HStack {
                Text("Hello:").bold()
                Text("World")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(.black)
        }
    }
}
```

which renders as follows:

[image]

When I add a `Divider()` into the `VStack`…

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Title").font(.title)
            Divider() // Added this
            HStack {
                Text("Hello:").bold()
                Text("World")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(.black)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

… it forces the `VStack` to expand horizontally as large as possible.

[image]

How do I make the `Divider` fit to the other `VStack` content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having written the question, I tried some more things, and found a solution. Leaving here in case it is useful for others.

I just needed to add

```
.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
```

to the `VStack`, which makes all the subviews have the same horizontal size, resulting in…

[image]